# NSMutableArray not adding anything with addObjectsFromArray

Tags: objective-c, count, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I am testing the AI for a card game and had issues when I noticed the *count* method of an **NSMutableArray** object was never increasing after using its *addObjectsFromArray* method. Not only am I using *addObjectsFromArray* in the test, but in a method for the AI to add an **NSArray** (or **NSMutableArray**), and in both cases, nothing is being added. In the test, I create a full, 52-card deck, shuffle, then deal the cards out to 3 AI's and an extra **NSMutableArray**.  Then I see what cards the AI already has, then see what each AI would play on its turn for a value, then add the cards it played back into its hand before moving on to the next AI.

Here's the code:

```
for(int k = 1; k < 14; k++)
{
     NSLog(@"-|-|-|-|-|- Current Value: %i", k);
     NSLog(@"----- Easy");
     [discard addObjectsFromArray:(NSArray*)[easy playHand:(NSUInteger)k]];
     NSLog(@"Discard's Count: %i", [discard count]);
     for(Card* cd in discard)
     {
         NSLog(@"card displayed = true");
         [cd displayCard];
         NSLog(@"card displayed = true");
     }
     //[discard makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(displayCard)];
      [easy addCards:discard];
      [discard removeAllObjects];

      NSLog(@"------ Medium");
     blah = (NSArray*) [Medium playHand:k];
     [discard addObjectsFromArray:blah];
     NSLog(@"Discard's Count: %i", [discard count]);
     //[discard addObjectsFromArray:[Medium playHand:(NSUInteger)k]];
     for(Card* cd in discard)
     {
         [cd displayCard];
     }
     //[discard makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(displayCard)];
      [Medium addCards:discard];
      [discard removeAllObjects];

      NSLog(@"------ Hard");
      [discard addObjectsFromArray:[HARD playHand:(NSUInteger)k]];
     for(Card* cd in discard)
     {
         [cd displayCard];
     }
     //[discard makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(displayCard)];
      [HARD addCards:discard];
      [discard removeAllObjects];
      NSLog(@" ");
      NSLog(@" ");
 }
```

From here, discard should be catching the cards played by playHand, which is returning an **NSMutableArray**, and *addObjectsFromArray* takes an **NSArray** (all pointers, of course). Should I not be passing them directly using the line below?

```
[discard addObjectsFromArray:[easy playHand:k]];
```

The quick work-arounds aren't working either, with using a separate pointer:

```
NSArray* blah = nil;
blah = [easy playHand];
[discard addObjectsFromArray:blah];
```

...or typecasting with a pointer (I tested this and it didn't work):

```
NSArray* blahblah = nil;
blahblah = (NSArray*)[easy playHand:k];
[discard addObjectsFromArray:blahblah];
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this not an automatic typecasting, or do I need to use another form of typecasting? Or is there something else I'm overlooking? I'll try to have it return an **NSArray** instead, but the container in the AI class is a **NSMutableArray** so I can add cards to it easily without creating copies of arrays every time a card object(s) is(are) added/removed. (PS: Yes, everything is properly created beforehand, I just snipped that part off because it made the code snippet pretty long. And the extra **NSMutableArray** holding the remaining 13 cards has *count* return 13 using *addObject*, but discard's count never changes from 0.)

Answer (score 0):

The usual problem is that `discard` is `nil`. I don't see it being initialized so I am guess that is the case here too.